# How did i setup popup AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

How did i setup popup AlertDialog  when int is equal or greater than 100?

```
 showDialog(
   context: _context,
   builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
     title: Text("$_winner Won"),
   )
 );



 void scoreTeamA() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamA += _choiceA;
    });
  }
// I would like to show outputTeamA  on the AlertDialog
```

Thank you
Mohammad

Comment: Could you share some more code that includes the int somewhere? Or what you have tried so far?

Comment: Does the text in the AlertDialog need to change following the initial `showDialog` call? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: add more code which are related to this. Example when you want to show. where this dialog is displayed. this dialog is any method? if yes then when this method get called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I display an `AlertDialog`

```
showAlertDialog() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 2.0),
        ),
        elevation: 6,
        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        title: Text(
          'This is the alert title',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        contentTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Content...')
            //content goes here
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), child: Text('Okay'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And then you would do your if check to check

```
if( outputTeamA >= 100){
showAlertDialog();
}
```

Of course you could use outputTeamA in `AlertDialog`

Comment: Are you still having this issue

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a Widget for the `AlertDialog` and pass the String/Widget you want to show on that dialog.

```
class LoadingDialog{
  static Future<void> showLoadingDialog(BuildContext context,String text) async {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return SimpleDialog(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height:10,
                      ),
                      Text(text),
                    ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      }
    );
  }
```

}

then you can call on an Event like:

```
void scoreTeamA(){
    outputTeamA += _choiceA;
    LoadingDialog.showLoadingDialog(context, outputTeamA);
}
```

Note: this code might have some errors. i haven't tested this.